# Tokenize string in C++

Tags: c++

If I have a sentence like

```
"Hello, I am going for a walk. I will be back home in an hour!"
```

How do I tokenize the string in C++ so that I get this output:

```
Hello
,
I
am
going
for
a
walk
.
I
will
be
back
home
in
an
hour
!
```

The tokenizers I've looked at removes special signs like period, comma etc. But in this case I want to treat these special signs as "words" as shown above.

Comment: Hint: check isspace: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/

Comment: All teokenizers I've ever met accept a "token parameter". Read up some more.

Comment: That seems a reasonable thing to implement. You need to try coding it yourself. Read one character at a time, output a linefeed when you switch from alpha to non-alpha and to spaces.  How are you supposed to treat sequences of special signs such as `...`?

Comment: @AlexandreCartaxo This isn't a whitespace tokenizer. It's a whitespace and punctuation tokenizer. `std::regex` is a good solution here.

Comment: Then ispunct (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/ispunct/) will solve the issue.

Comment: This isn't "tokenizing". This is "parsing".